# Getting connected vertex details and edge details from a known vertex

Tags: orientdb, pyorient

I have created class in pyorient ogm

```
class Movie(Node):
    element_plural = "Movies"
    title = String(mandatory=True,indexed=True)
    rating = Short()
class Person(Node):
    element_plural = "Person"
    name = String(mandatory=True,indexed=True)
class ACTS_IN(Relationship):
    element_plural = "ACTS"
    name = String()
    out_ = Link(linked_to=Person,mandatory=True)
    in_ = Link(linked_to=Movie,mandatory=True)
class PRODUCED(Relationship):
    element_plural = "Producers"
    out_ = Link(linked_to=Person,mandatory=True)
    in_ = Link(linked_to=Movie,mandatory=True)
```

How to I return all details of a particular Movie with actors and producers.
Should i call multiple queries for getting details of movie, actors and producers?

Select * from Movie where title='Test' 
select expand(ine()).in() from Movie where title = 'Test'

Will it not work as for foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select title, in("ACTS_IN").name as actors, in("PRODUCED").name as producers from Movie where title= "Test"
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can i get all details?  
select *, in("ACTS_IN").name as actors, in("PRODUCED").name as producers from Movie where title= "Test" 
This will give all vertex details of parent only. But how to get all details of connected vertex. If there are 10 properties  should i repeat  in("ACTS_IN").name as actors  with different params. I want

Answer (score 0):

If you are using orient DB 3.0 or greater version use following query to get details of a vertex and connected vertex

```
select *, ACTS_IN:{*} as actorDetails, PRODUCED:{*} as producerDetailss from Movie where title= "Test"
```